# Is there any difference between the idiom "that's about the size of it" and "that's about the extent of it"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference between the idiom *that's about the size of it* and *that's about the extent of it*? For example:

> Person A: What Kate's birthday party?
>
> Person B: She dropped her birthday cake. **That's about the size of it**./**That's about extent of it**.

Comment: Your cited context is a very poor one for these equivalent idiomatic expressions - which both mean ***That's all there is to it; I have nothing more to add***. Note that semantically it makes little difference whether we include the word ***about*** in either your examples, or my alternative ***That's about all there is to it***, but whereas ***about*** is entirely optional in my version, it's usually seriously unidiomatic not to include it with metaphorical ***size / extent***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both probably mean the same thing: "that's it, not much (or nothing) more".

But "that's about the size of it" is so uncommon in modern American English, it's almost a stretch for the reader to make the connection.